# Optimizing System of Non Linear Equations - Handling Complex Numbers

Tags: python, numpy, complex-numbers

I am trying to solve a system of non-linear equations. The issue is that the solutions are complex, with a very small imaginary portion according to Octave/Matlab. I am trying to move this over to python, but unfortunately I am not sure about how I should handle this elegantly.

In Octave, I can use fsolve directly, and then pass the solution through the "real" function to get the real portion of the numbers. The thing is, it easily solves it without returning any errors

Unfortunately, using numpy in python returns errors while trying to solve the equations. Here are the equations written in Python:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
import scipy.io as spio

params = dict()
params['cbeta'] = 0.96
params['cdelta'] = 0.1
params['calpha'] = 0.33
params['cgamma'] = 1.2
params['clambda']= 1.0
params['csigma'] = 0.8
params['etau'] = 0.0

def steady_s(vars0):
    # unpacking paramters
    cbeta = params['cbeta']
    cdelta = params['cdelta']
    calpha = params['calpha']
    cgamma = params['cgamma']
    clambda= params['clambda']
    csigma = params['csigma']

    # guesses for initial values
    c = vars0[0]
    y = vars0[1]
    k = vars0[2]
    g = vars0[3]
    r = vars0[4]

    # == functions to minimize to find steady states == #
    f = np.empty((5,))

    # HH Euler
    f[0] = (1.0/c)*cbeta*(r + 1.0 - cdelta) - (1.0+g)/c

    # Goods market clearing
    f[1] = y - c - k*(1.0 + g) + k*(1.0-cdelta)

    # Capital Market clearing
    f[2] = r - (k)**(calpha-1.0)*calpha**2.0

    # production function for final good
    f[3] = y - k**calpha

    # growth rate
    pi = (calpha - 1.0) * k**calpha #small pi, this isnt actual profits
    f[4] = g - (cgamma - 1.0) * clambda * (csigma*clambda*pi)**(csigma/(1.0-csigma))

    return f

# == Initial Guesses == #
vars0 = np.ones((5,))

# == Solving for Steady State == #

xss = fsolve(steady_s, vars0)
```

Implementing the same thing in Octave gives this solution:

```
 Columns 1 through 3:

   0.7851388 + 0.0000000i   0.8520544 + 0.0000000i   0.6155938 + 0.0000000i

 Columns 4 and 5:

   0.0087008 - 0.0000000i   0.1507300 - 0.0000000i
```

I pass this solution through the "real" function in Octave to give me the results I want.

In particular, python is having difficulty in even solving the equations once. In particular if I try and run f[4] outside the function with all the parameters defined, it returns a nan value.

Any help would be appreciated!

Apologies in advance to anything I've missed/formatted-badly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, scipy struggles with complex numbers. However, a project called mpmath can solve your case. Here: http://mpmath.org/. It used to come with sympy (sympy.org). You can find documentation [here](https://docs.sympy.org/0.7.0/modules/mpmath/calculus/optimization.html): This solution works for me:

```
from mpmath import findroot
import numpy as np
import scipy.io as spio

params = dict()
params['cbeta'] = 0.96
params['cdelta'] = 0.1
params['calpha'] = 0.33
params['cgamma'] = 1.2
params['clambda']= 1.0
params['csigma'] = 0.8
params['etau'] = 0.0

def steady_s(c,y,k,g,r):
    # unpacking paramters
    cbeta = params['cbeta']
    cdelta = params['cdelta']
    calpha = params['calpha']
    cgamma = params['cgamma']
    clambda= params['clambda']
    csigma = params['csigma']

    # guesses for initial values
    #c = vars0[0]
    #y = vars0[1]
    #k = vars0[2]
    #g = vars0[3]
    #r = vars0[4]

    # == functions to minimize to find steady states == #
    f = [0,0,0,0,0]

    # HH Euler
    f[0] = (1.0/c)*cbeta*(r + 1.0 - cdelta) - (1.0+g)/c

    # Goods market clearing
    f[1] = y - c - k*(1.0 + g) + k*(1.0-cdelta)

    # Capital Market clearing
    f[2] = r - (k)**(calpha-1.0)*calpha**2.0

    # production function for final good
    f[3] = y - k**calpha

    # growth rate
    pi = (calpha - 1.0) * k**calpha #small pi, this isnt actual profits
    f[4] = g - (cgamma - 1.0) * clambda * (csigma*clambda*pi)**(csigma/(1.0-csigma))

    return f

# == Initial Guesses == #
vars0 = list(np.ones((5,)))

# == Solving for Steady State == #
xss = findroot(steady_s, vars0)
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks for this